# Regular Expression for all strings that doesn't contain aa, bb or cc

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

Σ={a,b,c},
we want to describe a regular expression to contain all strings without double letters (aa, bb, cc).
I really have no idea how should I do this and I will be so glad if anyone could help me. 
thanks.

Comment: It might not be in your language, but `!(aa|bb|cc)` would work.

Comment: I'd find it easier to construct an NFA for this language and then convert it into a regular expression.